# Fitting a simple model first, then training a neural network on the error

Tags: regression, neural-networks, ensemble-learning

Can someone tell me what the name is for the following process?

I have some data with inputs $x_i$ and outputs $y_i$, and I fit a simple model (e.g. linear regression) to them.  Then, I compute the residual errors, and refine the model by training a neural net to predict them.

We could generalize this idea by jointly optimizing the parameters of the simple model and the neural network at the same time.  Is this considered "ensemble stacking"?  Or maybe it's just a particular kind of loss function you can attach to an existing neural network?  Any suggestions are helpful, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Isn’t this the gist of gradient boosting, fitting a model and then fitting another model on the residuals?

Comment: Yes!  But gradient boosting is just for random forests right?  I was thinking about this same concept but for general models.  And thanks for the welcome!

Comment: Boosting is often used with small trees, but it is a very general approach that would cover your situation as well. Maybe also of interest (regarding simultaneous estimation): https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3320525

Comment: @MichaelM thanks, that's a great find!  Yes that's what I'm describing.

Comment: You could also view the linear model as a (perhaps non-standard) component of your neural network, i.e. a specialised kind of neuron, with a funky loss function designed to weight the linear model part more strongly than the residuals part.

Answer (score 4):

What you've described sounds similar to gradient boosting, in that you sequentially estimate residuals. I think gradient boosting is additionally characterised by the models being weak. In your case it sounds like you have a strong learner in the mix, so it's not exactly the same as gradient boosting, although it shares some principles.

I've previously described your kind of algorithm as "sequential residual regression", and provided a tutorial-esque code example with plotting at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76847013/21896093

I think ensemble stacking is where you have multiple models feeding (in parallel) into a 'blender' model - the blender combines the model outputs into a more refined final prediction.

---

**Update** Enquiry in comments about jointly optimizing the models in the sequence, which I think can be done using PyTorch or similar. The code example below defines a `JointSequentialResidualRegressor` class. It takes in a list of models - in this case a linear regression model and a neural net. It fits the first model on `y`, and subsequent models on the residuals. The optimisation step optimises over all parameters jointly, aiming to predict `y` by minimising the error of each model.

The class supports an arbitrary number of models, and `y` can be multi-dimensional (2D in the dataset below).

[image]

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#
#Toy dataset
#
np.random.seed(0)
N = 1_000
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(t) ** 2 + t / 10 + np.cos(2 * t) ** 2 + np.log(t + 1)

test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'feature0': t ** 0.5 + np.random.randn(N) / 5,
     'feature1': np.sin(t) ** 2 + np.random.randn(N) / 5,
     'feature2': np.cos(2 * t) ** 3 + np.random.randn(N) / 5,
     'y0': y,
     'y1': np.log(y) * 3 + 1
     }
)

#
# Preprocess the data
#
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

features = test_df.drop(columns=['y0', 'y1'])
targets = test_df[['y0', 'y1']]

X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(features)

#To tensors
X_t = torch.tensor(X_scaled).float()
y_t = torch.tensor(targets.values).float()

#
#Setup models
#
n_features = features.shape[1]
n_outputs = targets.shape[1]

torch.manual_seed(0)

#Linear regression model
linear_regression = nn.Linear(n_features, n_outputs)

#Neural net model
neural_net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(n_features, n_features), nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(n_features, 2 * n_features), nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(2 * n_features, n_features), nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(n_features, n_outputs)
)

models_list = [linear_regression, neural_net]

#This class regresses each model on the
# previous model's residuals, and accumulates
# the MSE error
class JointSequentialResidualRegressor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, models_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.models_list = nn.ModuleList(models_list)
    
    def forward(self, X, y):
        target = y
        cum_residual_loss = 0
        for i, model in enumerate(self.models_list):
            prediction = model(X)
            cum_residual_loss = cum_residual_loss + nn.MSELoss()(target, prediction)
            residual = target - prediction
            target = residual
        
        predictions_permodel = [model(X) for model in self.models_list]
        final_predictions = torch.stack(predictions_permodel, axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)
        return final_predictions, cum_residual_loss

#
# Train setup
#
sequential_regressor = JointSequentialResidualRegressor(models_list)
optimizer = torch.optim.NAdam(sequential_regressor.parameters())

n_epochs = 20
batch_size = 16

#Wrap data in a DataLoader for shuffling & batching
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(list(zip(X_t, y_t)), shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)

#Train loop
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    for batch_num, (X_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(dataloader):
        yhat, cum_residual_loss = sequential_regressor(X_batch, y_batch)
        
        #Backprop
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        cum_residual_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
    print(f'[epoch {epoch + 1:>2d}] train loss: {cum_residual_loss.item():>6.3f}')

with torch.no_grad():
    yhat, _ = sequential_regressor(X_t, y_t)

#
#Plot
#
yhat_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'predicted y0': yhat[:, 0],
    'predicted y1': yhat[:, 1]
})
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))
lines = ax.plot(features, color='0.7', label='features')
f.legend(lines[0:1], ['features'])
targets.plot(color=['purple', 'royalblue'], linewidth=3, ax=ax)
yhat_df.plot(linewidth=1.5, linestyle=':', color=['purple', 'royalblue'], ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('sample index')
ax.set_ylabel('value')
ax.set_title('Linear regression + neural net in a\nJointSequentialResidualRegressor() architecture')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  Yes that's just what I had in mind.  Interesting that you had to come up with a name yourself like that =)  Does your code work even if X1 and X2 are the same feature set?

Comment: No problem. Yes you can have `X1` and `X2` the same. The OP of that question wanted the flexibility of having an `X` per model, which is why that implementation is multi-input. For the name I ended up just stringing together the 3 things the model does. It may have a name in the literature that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Last question:  your code passes the result of each regressor to the next one, which is then fitted.  Can you envision a way to have the same process, but all the parameters are optimized simultaneously?  So you don't fix the first regressor and pass to the second, but optimize all at once?

Comment: In scikit-learn the models are modular, in that each model has its own `.fit()` function wherein the optimisation takes place. To me it's not clear how the underlying optimisers for different models could be linked up in scikit-learn. A framework that works for this task is something like PyTorch. You can define your sequence of models, and register all their parameters with a single optimiser. The optimiser can then tune all parameters simultaneously.

Comment: I've updated my post with a code example where the model parameters are optimised over jointly.